# Cant get accessoryButtonTappedRowWithIndexPath to work in my StoryBoard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

***Shocking, this Issue still is NOT resolved(9/25/12).  Have researched within my multiple books and other experienced iOS developers on this issue.  I would have thought adding the pushViewController code would have fixed it but no resolve.  If anyone can assist me with this please let me know? THE BOUNTY STILL STANDS FOR THIS QUESTION, IF ANYONE KNOWS THE ANSWER TO THIS ISSUE.***

I am trying to build out code for the accesoryButtonTappedRowWithIndexPath method within my app but I am having trouble finding how, when you click on each individual disclosure button it goes to a new UI View Window.  I have bought a couple of books like Beginning IOS 5 Development.  In the Table Views section I see an example of how it is done but I can't seem to get it going in mine.  This is the code I have for it right now listed below.  The message class where I am trying to display a "message" when the disclosure button is selected to prove that it is working is not pulling up.  I see that it is accessible in the code from the book but I can not get it to work in mine, so I can have it go to the next view.  Can anyone assist me on this possibly? The screen show below shows that my other method action when you click on the table's cell works as the message alert pops up fine.

Many thanks.

[image: 3rd]
[image: 2nd]
[image: 1st]
[image: nbhoodcontroller_push]
[image: ns_log]

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


if (NbhoodDetailController == nil) 
{
    NbhoodDetailController = [[LWWDisclosureDetailController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LWWDisclosureDetail" bundle:nil];

}
NbhoodDetailController.title = @"Getting Neighborhood Details";
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSString *SelectedNeighborhood = [ListBlocks objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *DetailMessage = [[NSString alloc]
                           initWithFormat:@"You pressed the button for the Neighborhood   %@ to invest in.", SelectedNeighborhood];
NbhoodDetailController.title = SelectedNeighborhood;
NbhoodDetailController.message = DetailMessage;// <-- the "message" class isn't accessible for some reason as well so I can click on the disclosure button and give a message.
```

Cell for Row at Index code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath//returns instances of the UITableViewCell class rows that have to     be populated into the table view.  
{
static NSString *NeighborhoodDBListCellIdentifier = @"NeighborhoodDBListCellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NeighborhoodDBListCellIdentifier];//as table view cells   scroll off the screen, they are placed into a queue of cells available to be reused. So im   using those cells for the new rolls that scroll on the screen to assign them to.

if(cell == nil)//in case of no spare reuseable cells we create new ones here. If   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier doesn't have any to spare.
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
            reuseIdentifier:NeighborhoodDBListCellIdentifier];
}
//assigning the images for the rows and also the disclosure buttons for each row
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rowControlsIcon.png"];
cell.imageView.image = image;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;


NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
cell.textLabel.text = [ListBlocks objectAtIndex:row];//the output results of what the    cell is goes to the textLabel in the TableViewCell as text.  Like "Armour Neighhborhood"

return cell;


}
```

[image: example of how I have the segue working for another one of my screens that switch over fine]

Comment: Can I see your `cellForRowAtIndex` code.

Comment: Yes, I just added it for you within the original post. thanks.

Comment: If you put an NSLog in accesoryButtonTappedRowWithIndexPath does it produce anything?

Comment: Let me try..one moment..

Comment: Ok I added the screenshot of it.  It did show that I clicked on the Disclosure button for the correct neighborhood. If you look at the log  output in the screenshot....

Comment: You'll want to use `%ld` to log indexPath.row, and NbhoodDetailController is a view controller right? If so I don't see any code here telling it to be pushed to or presented.

Comment: Yes it is.  Okay thanks, I have it doing a push within the storyboard to the Disclosure Button Detail Controller.  I still have to write the code even when I have it built within the storyboard?  I attached the screenshot of it, up above as well.

Comment: Right, if you are linking your segues in storyboard to your cells, these segues will not also be applied to the detail disclosure buttons.

Comment: Ok so do I do a: pushViewController:NbHoodDetailController animated:YES]; ?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: The NeighborhoodDetailController isn't a navigation controller so i wouldn't do [self.navigationController pushViewController:NbhoodDetailController animated:YES] right?  Which code could I use exactly?

Comment: If you want to present it modally which is really your only other option you could use `[self presentViewController:NbhoodDetailController animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: When i placed in that code it crashed the app with this error below.  

2012-09-05 13:52:37.318 BlockVest[2350:f803] The row is 0 at location of Armour Square
2012-09-05 13:52:37.322 BlockVest[2350:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/macuser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/79CEE097-49CF-41E2-8829-91BF69F4E62F/BlockVest.app> (loaded)' with name 'LWWDisclosureDetail''

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with the DetailDisclosure xib file that is supposed to show the details after you click on the Disclosure button?

Comment: That did not seem to work for me NSPostWhenIdle?  Which bundle should the XIB file be in that it is saying exactly?  The NeighborhoodDetailController is the app delegate and the data source as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to just create the new controller you want to display. You also have to pass it along to the navigation controller at the end of your `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` method, like this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:NbhoodDetailController
                                     animated:YES];
```

Comment: That's what I tried already yesterday and it didn't work. I even tried that before I asked the question on the forum.  Not sure why this isn't working for me.  Did you see the error I got from this up in the previous section working with NSPostWhenIdle?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice all the other comments! Instead of passing nil as the bundle, use [NSBundle mainBundle].

Comment: That's okay Jack, we were chatting for a while on it :(  Not sure if I am following.  You mean like this?  I don't believe that works?  You must be speaking of something else correct?  As it is sending it to a incompatible parameter type.


[self presentViewController:NbhoodDetailController animated:YES completion:[NSBundle mainBundle]]

Answer (score 0):

Breaking out of the earlier comment thread... I think your problem is in the creation of your controller. Instead of this:

```
NbhoodDetailController = [[LWWDisclosureDetailController alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"LWWDisclosureDetail"
    bundle:nil];
```

do this:

```
NbhoodDetailController = [[LWWDisclosureDetailController alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"LWWDisclosureDetail"
    bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

This is just a guess, really. It would be interesting to step through and see what's actually being successfully created.

Comment: Thanks Jack.  Yes I figured out what you meant when you told me to try that.  And I placed it in and still the same result.  When I click on the disclosure button it shows in my NS Log that it is working fine and selecting the corresponding disclosure button row.  Is there anything else you would like to see in the code to help me troubleshoot?

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference since passing `nil` makes it default to the main bundle.

Comment: Right, nil or [NSBundle mainBundle] makes no difference here. Bad guess!  This is one of those things that is really hard to debug out of context. But if I had your project in front of me, I could probably solve it in a few minutes. Feel free to send me a copy if you want me to take a look. gmail account, jnutting.

Comment: Hi Jack, I just saw this post.  I've checked back multiples and it is odd that I am just seeing this, my regards.  I'll send you a zip of my xcode folder tonight.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using storyboards, you need to instantiate your view controllers with
 `- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`  on your UIStoryboard

Example :

```
// if your storyboard file name is MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard then use @"MainStoryboard_iPhone" as the parameter
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"
                                                     bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
NbhoodDetailController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your view controller identifier"];
// You need to set the view controller identifier in IB
```

Then you can push it to the navigation stack

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Another way to do it is to use a segue.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, been away on travel.  Yes I have did the seque portion and that is what I have for it. And for some reason it still isn't pushing it.  I shouldn't still have to instatiate the controllers if I have the seque correct? I'll upload the screenshots of it once I get logged on to my macbook.